# Bootstrap 4 row breaks for no reason

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, row

I know there have already been questions on this subject, but none of the solutions I found here were helpful. Hopefully someone can help me here:
I have a row with 4 columns of data as follows:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
<hr class="mb-4">
    <div>
        <h3>{{ player.full_name }}</h3>
        <h4> {{ player.position }}</h4>
        <h5> {{ player.team }}</h5>
    </div>
    <hr class="mb-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
            <div class="text-center font-weight-bold">
                Form
            </div>
            <div class="text-center ">
                {{ player.form }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
            <div class="text-center font-weight-bold">
                Price
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <span>&#163;</span>{{ player.price }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
            <div class="text-center font-weight-bold">
                Total
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                {{ player.total_points }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
            <div class="text-center font-weight-bold">
                TSB
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                {{ player.tsb }}%
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As far as I understand, the 4 columns should keep in one row even in smaller screen, especially as there is definitely enough space to show them all together. On small screens this is what I get:
[image]

Nothing I change seem to help in this matter. I would like all columns to be shown in the same row even on smaller screens. Appreciate your help

*Edit*
The source of the problem is in the  of my page.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Varela+Round">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.20/b-1.6.1/cr-1.5.2/r-2.2.3/sl-1.3.1/datatables.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.20/b-1.6.1/cr-1.5.2/r-2.2.3/sl-1.3.1/datatables.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

So the problem is when using the Bootstrap 4 tag instead of Bootstrap 3 like in the example below. Is that by design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want it to be in 4 columns at any device width, just use the class `col-3` instead `col-xs-3 col-sm-3`

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to reproduce this on my end. My guess is there's some difference in your CSS somewhere:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../docs-assets/ico/favicon.png">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
<hr class="mb-4">
    <div>
        <h3>Mohamed Salah</h3>
        <h4>Midfielder</h4>
        <h5>Liverpool</h5>
    </div>
    <hr class="mb-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
            <div class="text-center font-weight-bold">
                Form
            </div>
            <div class="text-center ">
                7.5
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
            <div class="text-center font-weight-bold">
                Price
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <span>&#163;</span>12.8
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
            <div class="text-center font-weight-bold">
                Total
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                165
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
            <div class="text-center font-weight-bold">
                TSB
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                45.3%
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

test it out and see:
https://codepen.io/davidgbiggs/pen/JjdXpGq

Comment: Hi, I was able to find the source of the problem. It is in the <head> of my page, when I replace it in your example it behaves the same as mine, see my edited code in the post